# LISP function that takes 2 lists as parameters

Tags: common-lisp, practical-common-lisp

After briefly talking about LISP in a past class, I have decided to jump in head first and try to learn [CLISP](http://clisp.org) (reading [Seibel's PCL](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) chpt 5). My question is in regards to writing a function that takes a set of lists as parameters. The first list is a series of indexes mapped to the second list. I want to pass a sequence of indexes and have it return the corresponding elements.

Here is the outline of my code so far. I wasn't sure if I could use nth and pass a list of arguments to it. I am not sure what the body-form should look like.

sys-info: CLISP 2.49 Win7

```
(defun get-elements('(nth (x y z) '(a b c)) )  
  "takes a list of arguments that returns corresponding elements from a list."
  (format t "The elements at index ~d are: ~%" x y z)
  ((maybe indexes go here)'(elements go here?))
```

The list `(x y z)` are the indexes and the data list `(a b c)` is some list of arbitrary elements. The evaluation is passed as data to the function get-elements. Am I even on the right track with this line of thinking?

Hints and pointers to relevant topics in LISP education are greatly appreciated.

postmortem:
Upon re-examination of chpts 3-4, it would seem that PCL is a bit of a reach for a beginning programmer (at least for me). I can enter the code from the book, but I obviously don't have a deep understanding of the basic structure of the language. I will probably try a few gentler introductions to Lisp before undertaking PCL again.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: There is a reason why a book is organized in chapters. Starting with chapter 5 of a book about a _new_ language is unlikely to be a good idea. Why don't you start with chapter 1?

Comment: I should clarify that I have made it to chpt 5. After making the ripped CD db in chpt 3 I was hooked.

Comment: I would like the code to eventually do something like this (get-elements 0 1 0) -> (a b a)

Comment: If you did read the previous chapters, how come you have the quote in the lambda list of your function?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will go back through 3-4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure if this is what you are asking about, but you might want to try:

```
(defun get-nth (index-list data-list)
  (mapcar (lambda (index)
            (nth index data-list))
          index-list))
(get-nth '(0 1 0 2 0 3) '(a b c d e f))
==> (A B A C A D)
```

Please take a look at

- [`mapcar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm)
- [`nth`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nth.htm)
- [Formatted Output](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_c.htm) - your `format` call is broken
- [Lather, Rinse, Repeat: A Tour of the REPL](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/lather-rinse-repeat-a-tour-of-the-repl.html) - you claim to have read it, but you obviously posted your code before pasting it into a REPL, so please review it again.

More gentle introductions to Lisp:

- [ANSI Common Lisp by Graham](http://www.paulgraham.com/acl.html)

Comment: Thank you, that is more than enough to get me started. fwiw, most of my self-generated code barfed in the repl. I will be more careful when posting code in the future.